# Reorder list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to rearrange a list according to the occurrence of length of sublists from small to large.For example,the expected answer is rearranged by the number of the length of sub-list,there is one length of 4,two length of 1, three length of 3 and four length of 2.

Example query and its result:

```
lists_ascending([[a,b],[c],[a,b,c],[d,d,d],[d,s],[s],[d,s,s,a], [s,a],[s,t],[a,b,w]],Ls).
Ls = [[d,s,s,a],[c],[s],[a,b,c],[d,d,d],[a,b,w],[a,b],[d,s],[s,a],[s,t]]
```

My idea is that to calculate each length first and then do rearrangement. What I have done so far is to collect the number of sublist whose length is equal to the first sublist using the pattern [length-number].

```
count([],[0-0]).
count([A|B],[L-N]):-
    length(A,L),
    same_length(B,L,M),
    N is M+1.

same_length([],_,0).
same_length([A|B],L,N) :-
    (   length(A,L)->
        same_length(B,L,M),
        N=M+1
    ;   same_length(B,L,N)
    ).
```

The count(LIST,X) output is as followed:

```
21 ?- count_slot([[2],[3],[4],[2,3,4]],X).
X = [1-3].
```

But the expected output is [1-3,3-1], I don't know how to deal with the rest sublist(remove one by one??) and rearrange them according to the pattern [1-3,3-1].

Can somebody help? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for the case that there may be *multiple* sublists of the same length as the first sublist. Clearly, your `count/2` only ever describes the case where there is at most a single one of them, because its second argument is a list of length 1.

To gather the sublists of the same length as the first sublist, consider for example:

```
lists_same_length_as_first([Ls|Lss], Subs) :-
    length(Ls, L),
    phrase(length_sublists(L,Lss), Subs).

length_sublists(_, []) --> [].
length_sublists(L, [Sub|Subs]) -->
    (   { length(Sub, L) } -> [Sub]
    ;   []
    ),
    length_sublists(L, Subs).
```

which you can also write more compactly by using `include/3`:

```
lists_same_length_as_first([Ls|Lss], Subs) :-
    length(Ls, L),
    include(length_equal(L), Lss, Subs).

length_equal(L, Ls) :- length(Ls, L).
```

Example query and its result:

```
?- lists_same_length_as_first([[2],[3],[4],[2,3,4]], Ls).
Ls = [[3], [4]].
```

By the way, I gave a complete solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274395/rearrange-list-element-prolog).

Comment: If you use List = ([[2],[3],[4],[2,3,4]], Ls).
Then the expected result is LS=[[2,3,4],[2],[3],[4]].
Because there is only one sublist whose length is three, and three sublist whose length is only one. This question is different from that one. Read carefully~~

Comment: That's also the result you get: `?- lists_ascending_appearences([[2],[3],[4],[2,3,4]], Ls).` yields: `Ls = [[2, 3, 4], [2], [3], [4]].`